# How to echo a string into a file that is prefixed by a period "." in a sh script

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I am attempting to generate a file that is prefixed by a '.' which will contain the contents of a variable. For example:

```
echo $var > .filename
```

After I execute the above line, I am unable to see the file. When I remove the '.' I can see the file.

Is there a way to escape it?

Comment: How about using " or ' or `?

Comment: "*This does not work*" - so, what happens?  How do you know your problem is caused by the `.`?   Works for me.

Comment: The file you are trying to write has _write_ permissions? may be a hidden file?

Comment: It *is* hidden, by definition, if it starts with a dot. A funny resolution would be if everything was created all right but you just wouldn't *see* it in the dir listing. (Tried `cat .filename` or `ls -a`?) But I suppose it may rather some difference between linux bash (where this command indeed works all right) and your unix, as others said.

Comment: Ah yes it is hidden. You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that a prefixed by '.' are hidden by default. running the following command displays the file:

```
ls -a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code works on my system (macOS 10.12), but you can escape the `.` with a backslash `\` like this:

```
echo $var > \.filename
```

Alternatively you can just wrap the target in quotation marks like so:

```
echo $var > ".filename"
```

Comment: Neither of those is necessary, as `.` doesn't have any special meaning to the shell.

Comment: Yeah as I mentioned, it works fine on my system and I imagine it would work on others, but I thought perhaps this user was on an obscure system. As other commenters have mentioned, likely the user didn't see it because it was hidden and should try `ls -a`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using centOS. The following works for me.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "abc" > .hidden
    echo "def" >> .hidden
    echo "gdhi" >> .hidden
    x=$1
    echo "$x" >> .hidden

    [localhost@localhost ~]$./writehidden.sh testwritedata

    [localhost@localhost ~]$ cat .hidden
    abc
    def
    gdhi
    testwritedata
```